# Al hacer click en botón, me abre dos veces la misma ventana nueva

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un botón en mi header "VISITAR MI TIENDA" que al hacer click abre en 2 ventanas iguales las tiendas.
Debería abrir UNA sola ventana nueva con la URL de la tienda.

La funcion que realiza esto es la siguiente pero no se si hay un error ahi o a que se debe esa doble apertura de la misma url.

```
/**
 * Si clickea en el boton "VISITA TU TIENDA" y nunca se publico muestra un modal, caso contrario redirige al sitio.
 */
$(document).on('click', '#viewSite', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var published = $(this).data('published');

    if (!published) {
        var dialog = $('#sitePublishedModal');

        dialog.dialog({
            'width': 500,
            'modal': true,
            'resizable': false
        });
    } else {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), "_blank");
    }
});
```

Comment: Puede que estés llamando dos veces a tu archivo JS, uno en la etiqueta `<header>` y otro antes de cerrar el body, verifica eso.

Comment: Podrias agregar tú codigo HTML para ver el lugar desde donde realizas el llamada.

Comment: Era exactamente eso @VickMuñoz , llamaba dos veces a la función JS . muchas gracias!

Comment: @NicolasSeguro no hay de que mi estimado :)